# Strings paddings and alignments

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have tried today to save a file using TextIo. Just 3 lines:

```
Radio Station;MagicFM
Test;This is jost for testing purpose.
TV;TV_Brand
```

All good but then i read it.

[image]

I am not able to align the the things.

**Maybe something like:**

```
Radio Station         - MagicFM
Test                  - This is jost for testing purpose.
TV                    - TV_Brand
```

This is what i have in code:

```
info(strFmt("%1  - %2", strLFix( conPeek(con, 1), 20),conpeek(con, 2)));
```

I have played a bit with strRFix and strLFix but with no luck .. is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aligning output like this is not the intended use of `infolog`, and as Matej said, the reason is because of the font.  However, if you are wanting to use the infolog for display purposes, you probably will want to use it like this to get the following output:

```
static void Job114(Args _args)
{
    container       c, cc;
    int             i;

    c = [["Radio Station", "MagicFM"], ["Test", "This is jost for testing purpose."], ["TV", "TV_Brand"]];
    setPrefix("Output"); // SetPrefix is necessary to get the tabbing to function correctly
    for (i=1; i<=conLen(c); i++)
    {
        cc = conPeek(c, i);
        info(strFmt("%1\t%2", conPeek(cc, 1), conPeek(cc, 2)));
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, i saw you also mention that font just like Matej, but .. where do i change it?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing it, but it's the form `\Forms\SysInfologBrowser`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [*Fixed width font*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) like `Courier`. You can't align visually with variable width font.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `System.String.Format` method like:

```
str       s; 
s = System.String::Format("{0, -15} - {1, -15}", "Radio Station", "MagicFM");    
info(s);
```

See [Align String with Spaces](http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/), [strFmt Function [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa589727.aspx) and [String.Format Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.